# Will DIY.SE be allowing SE advertising?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know some of the other SE sites are utilizing some "cross-pollination" where, if related to the main topic, put up an advertisement if the community agrees to a connection. For example:

Movies.SE asked for ads and Mythology.SE provided this:

[image: Visit Mythology.SE!]

If DIY.SE was looking for something along this line, the site I most often frequent, which is Mechanics.SE seems like it has a logical connection to DIY.SE. There is nothing more DIY than working on your own car.

I've built several ads for different sites (most of which have been sadly shot down due to the site not finding the connection [Cooking.SE just didn't see the connection with Mechanics.SE, for some reason]), but would love to build a symbiotic relationship with DIY.SE. Let me know what you think. If DIY.SE had no inclination for doing the ads, it's no sweat off my brow.

Since Mechanics.SE is not a full fledged site yet (though we have been given guidance this may soon change) we cannot advertise other sites on it. I would suggest as soon as we are able, though, DIY.SE would be the first we'd solicit for such ads.

Comment: While DIY is the short name, the comparison is less relevant when you call it by the full title, "Home Improvement". We see a lot of cross over with Woodworking and some with Gardening. There some, but much less cross over with Mechanics, EE, and Arduino SEs.

Comment: @BMitch - The average DIY mechanic is most likely involved in Home Improvement as well (ie: Tim "The Toolman" Taylor comes to mind). The opposite is true as well ... I look at myself for that verification. If DIY.SE and Mechanics.SE were the same thing, they'd be one SE. I'm just suggesting there are similar patron interests between the sites, which indicates a crossover.

Comment: I may be oversensitive to the loose usage of DIY because we've closed a lot of questions about DIY topics that have nothing to do with home improvement. For the crossover, I'm looking at questions we migrate, where Woodworking and Gardening are the top two outbound destinations, and EE likes to throw a lot of random stuff our way. You may be right that actual users have a lot of crossover, but I didn't see much of that in the user active user list.

Comment: And none of what I say is to discourage the creation of crossover ads, really like seeing a motivated user base. Just giving you feedback on where we see the crossover from the mod side.

Comment: @BMitch - Which is actually what I would be promoting. If people already crossover, it becomes moot. I think we could assist each other in that sense. As for EE.SE ... if it has "car" anywhere in the body of the question, it gets sent to us ... doesn't matter if it's pertinent or not ... we get it. I guess what I'm saying there ... *don't feel lonely*. Most of them end up getting closed or sent back because they really have nothing to do with us.